# Angularjs - Restrict user from typing while user tabs out to new field if API call in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, promise

My mobile (ionic) application makes an API call when user types in something to an input field and do an 'onblur' (focus out) operation.

If user tabs to next input field, or he/she just tap on another input field, the 'onblur' happens and it makes API(ajax) call and a loader image comes up while the request is in process. This loader image on the front is supposed to restrict user from typing in to any of the input fields while the call is in process.

The problem I am facing is, even though there is this loader, user is able to type in characters as user gets already focussed on to next field before loader starts up. I want to restrict that from happening.

I have an angular directive for input elements - something like this:

```
...
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) => {

          elem.on('blur', event => {
              // some backend API call getting execute. I can get a promise back here.
              let promise = getData();
          }
          elem.on('focus', event => {

          }

      }
  };
});
```

I want to make the input field which user focuses to be disabled until the API promise resolves.

Note: I could do this with some event broadcasting and disabling/enabling the focussed field based on API promise resolved or not; but I feel this is more of a hack so wanted to see if any better solutions. Here is my current solution -

```
 elem.on('focus', event => {
  scope.$on('UPDATE_PROGRESS', () => {
    elem.attr('disabled', true);
  })


  scope.$on('UPDATE_COMPLETE', () => {
    elem.attr('disabled', false);
  })
}
```

And I broadcast these events before and then of API call.

I am using $ionicLoading to show the progress image while doing the api call.

Appreciate any suggestions on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to do this is not to do it at all because it's a bad user experience to disable fields intermittently.

Like, when you use google docs, they don't disable the doc every time they do a save. Instead, the save call is debounced, and they do a new call every time the user makes changes. So if a save call is already in progress, you don't need to prevent doing additional calls, you just essentially mark your state as "dirty" so that you do another save after maybe 1 second of the user not typing.

Comment: Thanks frodo2975 for the response. Unfortunately, on this application, I cannot debounce those calls due to various architectural reasons. Each input field has its own business scenarios and updates/creates other input fields dynamically - a little crazy I know.

Comment: Hmm, building a form dynamically isn't that crazy, but it still seems like you don't need to disable the fields. Why not just allow the user to edit it and do another call if you need to? A common pattern with things that do frequent calls, like search inputs, is to ignore the results of all calls except the most recent one.